# Generalization of free magmas for nested structures

Tags: reference-request, computer-science, trees, monoid, magma

Consider a nonempty set $X$. What is the name / concept that gives rise to (the set of) all $X$ labeled planar trees e.g.

```
      *
    /   \
   /      *
  *     /   \
 / \   x3    *
x1  x2     / | \
         x4  x5 x6
```

which could alternatively be described via a nested list
$$\Big[ \big[x_1, x_2 \big], \big[x_3, [x_4, x_5, x_6]\big] \Big]$$

or say

```
      ___ *___
    /     |    \
   /      x3     \
  *             __*__
 / \          /      *
x1  x2       x4    / | \
                 x5  x6 x7
```

which gives rise to the bracketing
$$\Big[\big[x_1, x_2\big], x_3, \big[x_4, [ x_5, x_6, x_7]\big]\Big]$$

One way that would almost make sense (but doesn't capture it) is something like the [free non-associative magma](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Free_magma) on the free monoid (or semigroup) on $X$ (if we want to avoid empty leaves.) The free monoid on $X$ would provide the ``associative bits'' i.e. the leaves i.e. the (arbitrary size) arrays $[x, y, z, \dots ]$ and the free magma on those provides all the non associative ways to concatenate them. The problem is only with the fact that the free magma is constructed recursively from *pairs* of elements in lower degrees. Here I allow $k\geq 1$ tuples. In other words I want to use the recursion

$$X_1 = X, ~X_p = \coprod_{\substack{n_1 + \cdots +n_r = p \\ 1\leq n_i, r\geq 1}} X_{n_1}\times\cdots\times X_{n_r}$$

So that for instance

```
*
|
*
|
x
```

(corresponding to $[[x]]$) is allowed

Such structures appear in computer science e.g. in [RLP encoding](https://ethereum.org/fr/developers/docs/data-structures-and-encoding/rlp/) which provides a way to encode nested structures. It seems to me that they also describe the (set of) $n$-ary operations of a free operad generated by one $n$-ary operations $\mu_n$ for every $n \geq 1$. I remember that (some form of) rooted planar trees are of importance in describing operations. I don't know anything about operads beyond simple definitions. I'm more interested in the computer-science-math description of these tings.

**Edit.** Maybe it can be described as the colimit of a system of sets defined as $X_1 = X$ and $X_{n + 1} = F(X_1 \sqcup X_2 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup X_n)$ where $F$ is the free semigroup functor?

**Edit 2** Or maybe like so: set $GX = X \sqcup FX$. There is a natural transformation $1_\mathrm{Set} \to G$ by inclusion in the first factor. Then define the set which this question is about as the colimit of the diagram

$$ X \to GX \to GGX \to \cdots$$

**Edit 3** the above doesn't work, it will generate $[x]$ twice ...

Comment: "The set of ordered trees with leaves labeled by elements of $X$" seems pretty clear, but I guess you're looking for a more algebraic or category-theoretic description.

Comment: Yes, I want some construction that produces what I want from simpler things, e.g. a colimit of a diagram or such.

Comment: Also probably not what you're looking for, but might as well note the fairly concise inductive definition e.g. in Haskell: `data T a = Leaf a | Node (List (T a))`.